# Is it possible to use a local IIS service in a UWP app

Tags: iis, uwp, webbrowser-control

Is it possible use have a web-browser control inside a UWP app that connects to a local web server?

I can have the app connect to a live service, but some users need to be able to get access to web pages while working off-line.

Ideally, I'd like to replicate the feature on a local service, but I can't find anything to support this sort of feature.  My guess is, it breaks the sandbox rule for UWP apps, but I thought there may be somebody that has been able to make this happen.

Comment: UWP has specific guides on how to convert a web app. Read those first.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert a web app.  I have a UWP application that has an embedded web-browser control.  I want to direct the control to either a web server (traditional) or a local web server (something running inside the sandbox on the user's computer).

Comment: Update the question to reflect that. Besides, what is technology you use to build the pages? Many should only require a server like Node.js, and neither IIS nor IIS Express can be embedded in your UWP app.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to update in my question.  I didn't say anything new in my response to your original comment.  Ideally, I would like the web pages to be served up from an ASP.Net service, but if that's not possible, then it's not possible.